# Functions different datatypes calculate rent

Tags: c, function, types, double

trying to make a function which calculate the total sum with rent of a starting amount.
My printf("%.1f", calcFutureValue[i]); don't want to work for some reason, i did a lookup if it had to do with the different datatypes, since numberOfYears is an int but not sure.
What i'am missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double calcFutureValue(double startingAmount, double interest, int numberOfYears);


int main()
{
    double startingAmount = 10000;
    double interest = 1.045;
    int numberOfYears = 3;

    calcFutureValue(startingAmount, interest, 3);


    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfYears; i++)
    {
        printf("%.1f", calcFutureValue[i]);
    }
    getchar();

    return 0;
}


double calcFutureValue(double startingAmount, double interest, int numberOfYears)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfYears; i++)
    {
        startingAmount * interest * pow(numberOfYears, 2);
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Your resource for learning C is doing you a great disservice. You seem to be confused about how program flow works.

Comment: `printf("%.1f", calcFutureValue(startingAmount, interest, i + 1));` instead. You should learn how function works and other fundamental stuffs.

Comment: Ther aren't enough arguments...  surely, this cannot compile?

Comment: `calcFutureValue()` is a function.  What is code trying to accomplish with using it like an array with `calcFutureValue[i]`?  "My printf("%.1f", calcFutureValue[i]); don't want to work for some reason" because the code is not legal C code.  Post your compiler error rather than using an indefinite description like "don't want to work for some reason"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>

 double calcFutureValue( int numberOfYears);

 const double startingAmount = 10000;
 const double interest = 1.045;

 int main()
 {
     int numberOfYears = 3;
     int i;

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfYears; i++)
    {
        printf("%.2f\n", calcFutureValue(i));
    }

    return 0;
 }


 double calcFutureValue(int numberOfYears)
 {
    return startingAmount * pow(interest, numberOfYears);
 }
```

Explanation:
    There was a mistake with the compound interest formula.
    Since this is dealing with currency,  the decimal width of 2 is appropriate.
    Since startingAmount and interest are constants,  they can be constant global variables.

Comment: Thx Nguai al, i'll try to experiment a bit more to find a few ways to calculate it aswell. Thx <3